# How to handle "Promise { <pending> }" in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have this function in javascript

const getData = async() =>  {

```
try {
    const serviceResponse = await someService("userId")
    return serviceResponse

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    
  }
}



const data = getData()
console.log(data)
```

Whenever I am running this I am getting this in console

```
 Promise { <pending> }
```

But when I am print data in the function itself I am getting the desired value

```
const getData = async() =>  {
 try {
     const serviceResponse = await someService("userId")
     console.log.(serviceResponse)

   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
    
  }
 }



 getData()
```

The following function is what I am importing from defined in another another

```
exports.someService = async(date,locationId,workerType) => {
    const value = await Attendance.find({})

    return value
}
```

Please can someone explain what is happening ?

Comment: `async` function always returns a promise. Any non-promise value returned from an `async` function is implicitly wrapped in a promise and returned. What you need to do to get the `serviceResponse`: `getData().then(serviceResponse => { ... })`

Comment: You need to _await_ your call to `getData`, ie. `await getData()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `await` the promise from `getData()` too -

```
const data = await getData()
```